# How to Insert hashmap into database table?

Tags: java, sql, hashmap

I have a hashmap with  pair. 
the key in this are column-names in a table Now I want to insert them into a table say users_table,
i should be able to match the key to the column names and if both are same then insert that value into table.

What I am doing is that i have to write preparedstatement with all the columns and then pass the hashmap values as parameter using setter methods of preparedsatatement.
For doing this i need to know all the columns of table and this would be tedious work as there would be no. columns and this step would be repeated to no.of tables.

tell me Any idea of doing this, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

First off, use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the order of the columns. This will make a difference when iterating over the map to assign column names and then values.

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you're hinting at what is called Object Relational Mapping (ORM). Simply put, it's a way to map database tables to plain old Java objects (POJO). Though there's a lot more to it than that.

If you're interested in representing your database tables as objects, you should look into Hibernate, which is a popular Java ORM API.

Otherwise, create and keep to a standard that is uniform across both your database and your Java project and you'll be fine.

Edit:

If I understand your question a little more, you're having issues with knowing the names of the columns? This is something you have to know, there's not going to be an easy, dynamic, or efficient way of getting that information.

One example of setting that information is storing the column names in a `String` array of a class that represents your table. You can then access the array and iterate over it when saving to a database.

And finally, if you feel like doing some reading, check out my answer ([Store nested Pojo Objects as individuall Objects in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726894/store-nested-pojo-objects-as-individuall-objects-in-database/19806383#19806383)). I go quite in-depth on how I manage Database to Java and vice versa.

Comment: yes, Hibernate will solve the problem, but i am not aware with hibernate. and will need to go through tutorials for that.

Comment: And i need to store the hashmap into table, the table column names and all the key names of map are same, So by getting the key name i need to store that value in the respective column name in the table. this is my exact requirement. the problem is there might be no. of columns in table  so i cant go for setter method of prepared statements. @abmitchel. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you show me what you've got so far in code, along with where you're having problems?